# Can i use session scoped bean instead of httpsession for maintaining sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans, httpsession

I'm stuck at this question. I've used httpsessions before. But this time, I got this thing to choose between the two. A session-scoped managed bean or an httpsession.

What do you suggest ? Please mention pros and cons of each.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two concepts here:
**Case For HTTPSession**: lets say you have a variable called `var_one` and you want to access `var_one` within a session across multiple managed beans (irrespective of whether they are session scoped or not), then you need to use HTTPSession to store this variable.

**Case Session Scoped Managed bean**: Incase you need to manipulate this `var_one` variable only within one specific session scoped managed bean, then you can directly keep it in this bean and use it through out the session.